# How to add a reply button for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When clicking on a button, 5 textboxes will be displayed. I have to add a button for reply to the last textbox - can anyone show me how?

This is my code:

```
protected void GenTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= TotalReplys; i++)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl lineBreak = new HtmlGenericControl("br");
        Page.Controls.Add(lineBreak);

        TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();

        MyTextBox.ID = i.ToString();
        MyTextBox.Width = 540;
        MyTextBox.Height = 60;
        MyTextBox.Text = "Get the value from the database";
        MyTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        Panel1.Controls.Add(MyTextBox);

        Panel1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens when you run the code? You haven't described a problem.

Comment: @amicable HI, Total 5 textboxs are created .but I have to create a reply link button for the last text box ,This is my prbm

Comment: No, that's not a problem, that's a requirement. Once you've attempted to complete your requirement, you may run into problems that we're glad to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are on the right track. Use the same code that you have for generating a textbox, but repurpose it to generate a button.

**Here are some hints to get you on the right track**

```
if ( i == TotalReplys ){
  Button MySearchButton = new Button();
  //Set Button Properties
  Panel1.Controls.Add(MySearchButton);
}
```

I imagine you are either hung up on the if-statement logic or perhaps not aware of the Button object. Either way, this should set you on the right track.